# Bragging about your skills in an email for getting a job interview

Tags: interviewing, applications, email

I'm replying to an email from an employer that tries to set a time with me for an interview and also asks me more questions about my skills and experiences. Besides writing an honest list of my skills, is it professional to write something like this at the end of the email:

"I'm confident that you won't be disappointed!"

Comment: You should consider waiting longer before awarding the "correct answer" in order to encourage more responses from users. A day or two would not be unusual. Some people with valuable insight may overlook your question because they can see that it has already been resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The time for your sales pitches is the interview, not the initial email. At this stage, it seems like they are trying to gauge whether you will be called for a phone/in-person interview first based on your qualifications, so leave the sales tactics out until you know you need them.

Comment: I roll my eyes every time I get something like this in a cover letter.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad I asked this question before sending the email.

Answer (score 6):

To add to @LawrenceAiello's answer, if you're looking for some way to sign off your email, a better way would be something like:

> I look forward to seeing you soon.

This gives an impression of confidence, that you are confident about the upcoming interview, but doesn't sound contrived or specious.

Comment: Yeah, much better - doesn't quite assume success, but shows enough confidence

Comment: I always end up with : "if you think that I might fit into your team, I look forward to discussing it further."